# How to create itemViewClass in ember cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to remove metamorph script tags because [salvattore](https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore) doesn't parse them correctly.  I am currently doing this with jquery remove() but this seems to cause errors in the _addMetamorphCheck() function which ember runs automatically.  My hope is a itemViewClass won't have the metamorph tags in it.

So how do I create a itemViewClass in my ember cli view?  Do I create a new view file or does it go in my current view file as an attribute?

**views/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        $('#grid script').remove();
        var grid = $('#grid')[0];
        salvattore.register_grid(grid);
    }
    //no idea how to define itemViewClass??
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck because the `metal-views` branch [just got merged into master](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5432). This branch removes all metamorph tags from your Ember app, and it should be a drop-in replacement with no backwards incompatibility.

Use `ember#master` today, and be rid of all your metamorph woes!

Comment: Not a solution to the problem. Shouldn't be marked as such.